# How to read local xml file is resource folder as a input stream in android?

Tags: android, xml, local

I am trying to get input stream from something like this.

```
InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(activity.getResources().openRawResource(com.MYCLass.R.xml.programs));

myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
```

and then call parse on the parser instance i Created. Some how i get nothing.
Works fine if I use a server XML....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the xml file into `/res/raw folder`. It looks like [openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) opens resources from that folder only. You can also try `getResources().getXml(com.MYCLass.R.xml.programs);` which will return you an instance of XML parser.

A piece of code taken from @Krupa

```
InputStream object = this.getResources()
                     .openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can read the file by the following code :

```
InputStream object = this.getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.rawFolderName.fileName);
```